# Using allure with JBehave and Lettuce

Tags: jbehave, lettuce, allure

We have 2 fairly large automation projects going, both using BDD. One is in Lettuce for a desktop app, the other is for a website using JBehave (we are just getting started with the web project).

We have tried using Thucydides for reporting for our JBehave project, and started implementing tests using that. However, we ran into Allure and it looks a lot better and lets us use standard JBehave framework without relying on someone's code that has its own unknown-to-us issues. Luckily, we found Allure early enough.

2 questions:

1) We spent 2 days trying to make Allure work with JBehave, but the only example on GitHub isn't working well (all scenarios are reported together without breakdown by individual stories or scenarios).  Also, JBehave doesn't have an @AfterStep decorator and it's a requirement for us to save screenshots after each step, successful or not. Thucydides for all its faults took care of that. Does Allure have something similar? If not, then at least is there a working example of how to make it report stories and scenarios correctly when run from JBehave?

2) I haven't tried yet, but doesn't look like there is an adapter for Lettuce (Python).  Can someone recommend a way to produce Allure reports from Lettuce?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the code you have tried. Post gives the problem statement only. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I was looking for a "getting started" instructions. Tried to run example project from here and ran into the described issues: https://github.com/SergTanchenko/allure

Answer (score 1):

Allure doesn't support *JBehave* and *Lettuce* yet. But you can implement such adapters by yourself.

First step you need to read the following section https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki#development in documentation. Then if you are ready to contribute you should follow the following instructions:

### JBehave

We already have Java adaptor. So all you need is add `allure-java-adaptor-api` module as dependency and then implement *JBehave* listener.

### Lettuce

There are the same. You can use allure-python bindings and all you need is implement *Lettuce* handlers. Python team are going to move bindings (aka `allure-python-adaptor-api`) to separate module, you can force it by comment in https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-python/issues/63

So, if you have any questions/suggestions you can also use our gitter chat room (https://gitter.im/allure-framework/allure-core) or our mailing list ([allure@yandex-team.ru](http://mailto:allure@yandex-team.ru))

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve integration between JBehave and Allure you can create your own implementation of `org.jbehave.core.reporters.StoryReporter`. From the methods in this interface you can fire the Allure events that correspondent to the JBehave abstractions. In our implementation we fire `TestSuite*Event`s from e.g. `StoryReporter#beforeStory()` and `TestCase*Event`s from e.g.`StoryReporter#afterScenario()`.

The caveat is that for some JBehave events you have to fire multiple Allure events. For example for a failed jbehave step we fire the following allure events:

```
public class AllureStoryReporter implements StoryReporter {

... 

    @Override
    public void notPerformed(final String step) {
        getLifecycle().fire(new StepStartedEvent(step).withTitle(step));
        getLifecycle().fire(new StepCanceledEvent());
        getLifecycle().fire(new StepFinishedEvent());
    }
}
```

Of course the created reporter needs to be registered to be used during reporting by JBehave.

This results in comprehensive Allure reports.

Answer (score 0):

At least for JBehave, the support [was added](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-java/tree/master/allure-jbehave) since then